# How do I make vscode c++ intellisense work with remote development?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, openssh

When running vscode locally on windows I can install the C/C++ extension and immediately have some code understanding from the editor (visual studio 2019 is installed too):

[image]

However after installing OpenSSH and connecting to the same PC via the vscode [Remote Development](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-release) extension (connecting from linux to Windows) this doesn't work:

[image]

Everything I hover over says: **`Unsupported Markup content received. Kind is:`**

Also typing `msg.<ctrl+space>` gives **`No suggestions.`**

The only references I can find are:

- https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-xml/issues/43
- https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient/pull/103/files#diff-fde961a63820de2855135d552feaef126f4624fa959efbe848c112a5fb04e4a5R180

These don't seem related. I have not set up a c_cpp_properties.json but then I didn't need to for the local test that worked. The error makes me think there is some conflicting extension, but I've uninstalled most others and the issue persists. What have I missed?